# Chapel eltType methods

Tags: chapel

I have a class which contains a field that has an array of eltTypes. This looks like this:

```
type eltType;
var size = 5;
var elementsDomain: domain(1) = {0..size-1};
var elements: [elementsDomain] eltType;
```

Later on, I have a method that utilizes this (still inside of the class) like this:

```
proc add(eltType el){
    elements[0] = el;
}
```

I get a compiler error that says it has a syntax error at the add method signature. I thought eltTypes worked like generic types in java. How exactly am I doing eltTypes wrong, and how are they supposed to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the type of el in the following format:

```
proc add(el : eltType) {
```

Chapel does a good job of figuring out types (except for fruitful recursive functions) so it should also work if you leave the type out and say:

```
proc add(el) {
```